# Connection refused from p2p-peer address for NODES-Producing Block

Tags: nodeos, block-producer

I am trying to **setup EOSIO production node** on Ubuntu. My specs are following:

**NAME="Ubuntu"**
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
with 62GB RAM and 500GB storage.
I have installed eosio using pre-built binaries. I want to setup node as producing node but connection refuse on p2p-peer address: my config is following:

**config.ini**

```
producer-name = atifmehmood1
signature-provider = <EOS-Pub key>=KEY:<EOS-Pvt key>
agent-name = Eosio.Identity

http-server-address = 0.0.0.0:8888
p2p-listen-endpoint = 0.0.0.0:9876
p2p-server-address = 172.31.91.78:9876


p2p-peer-address = 34.96.75.100:8099
```

**I am running Nodeos with following command:**

```
nodeos  --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin 
--plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin 
--http-validate-host=false --delete-state-history --delete-all-blocks >> nodes.log 2>&1 &
```

**But I am getting these error**:

[image]
[image]

I have tried lots of IPs from this link(https://github.com/superoneio/eos-mainnet/blob/master/config.ini) as p2p-peer address but still no luck. Kindly help me out here.

Comment: can try https://eosnodes.privex.io/?config=1 for up to date peers also at the bottom of this page https://validate.eosnation.io/eos/reports/endpoints.html

Comment: can also ask questions in the eosio developers channel, they'll definitely sort you out https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Answer (score 0):

I was not running through latest snapshot. I downloaded snapshot and ran Nodeos again with nodeso --snapshot /path/ and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I am facing some issues while running through snapshots , i am on ubuntu 18.04. Also to mention, i have installed pre-built binaries of eosio. Node is starting from 1st block but it was taking so much time so i tried using snapshots but its isnt working properly.
command used :

1. stop.sh
2. nodeos --snapshot /path  --force-all-checks